# Can I create a truly empty Profile without having to uncheck hundreds of boxes via the UI?

Tags: profile

**The goal**: A profile that has zero object access, zero field access, etc. I want all object and field access to be controlled by permission sets.

**The Attempt:**

**Via the SF UI**: You're in for a world of hurt. You have to create new profiles by cloning from existing, so there's no choice to *start* with an empty profile. You'd then need to click through literally hundreds of objects, one by one, with painful page load times, to then uncheck dozens of CRUD and FLS checkboxes on each object page. We're talking about painful busywork that would take *hours*. No thank you.

**Via SFDX**: I had hoped that working directly with metadata in SFDX would fix this problem. After all, a profile deployed by itself wouldn't bring over any object permissions, since they have to be included in the deployment, right?

Try this:

1. Pick a random profile in your SFDX metadata repo
2. Copy the file, change the filename to your new profile name, and delete everything from the XML except for the top level tags, so it looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <custom>true</custom>
        <userLicense>Salesforce</userLicense>
    </Profile>
```

3. Use SFDX to deploy profile to an org.

I would have expected a completely empty profile. No object settings, no system permissions, no nothing. That's what I'm clearly asking for given what's in the XML file, after all.

**NOPE**
What I got instead was basically a 'default' profile.
A whole bunch of system permissions checked that I wouldn't want these users to have.
All standard objects given full access.

I cannot fathom Salesforce's reasoning behind this limitation. It seems poorly designed, but, like, at a profound level.

Is there any better solution for my goal than having to manually uncheck boxes in the UI for the next 3 hours? Please god.

Comment: Clone the Minimum Access profile: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.standard_profiles.htm&type=5

Comment: lifesaver! Thank you

Comment: @identigral - you should post this as the answer

Comment: Relevant [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358005&type=1) and its [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=md-api-objectpermissions-of-newly-deployed-profile-showing-additional-permissions-which-are-not-even-part-of-profile-metadata&Id=a1p4V000001ZhtI) to explain the behavior noted

Comment: I'm finding currently that cloning this profile and then making ANY change - even just populating the description field - results in object permissions changing; similar to the known issue listed above, but through the UI, not the CLI

Comment: What about a different license type?  e.g. platform license

Comment: A platform license's standard profile certainly has fewer permissions, but its still not a blank profile. And besides, that comes with all the restrictions of a different license type.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves the link you provided doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to this known issue:
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwEpAAK/md-api--objectpermissions-of-newly-deployed-profile-showing-additional-permissions-which-are-not-even-part-of-profile-metadata

1. Manually clone a new profile from `Minimal Access`
2. Or build a full profile metadata with all `false` values for all standard objects and standard fields and standard tabs.